# Importing my original package

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to import my original package.
But it is said that there is no class files form Akirasda1972_001.as.
My package file is uploaded on sexydesign.club/particle/.

```
package{

  import flash.display.Sprite;

  import club.sexydesign.particle.Akirasada1972_001;

  public class akirasada1972_002 extends Sprite{

    private var akirasada1972_001:Akirasada1972_001;

    public function akirasada1972_002():void{
        akirasada1972_001=new Akirasada1972_001();
        akirasada1972_001.Akirasada1972_001();
        addChild(akirasada1972_001);
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: do you mean it is uploaded to a remote server?

Comment: `import club.sexydesign.particle.Akirasada1972_001` means that for where you stored **akirasada1972_002.as** for compiling, you must have the **...1972_001.as** file in this sub-folders structure... **club** / **sexydesign** / **particle** / **Akirasada1972_001.as**

Comment: Yes,  I have the program in there.